# No CAPTCHA ReCAPTCHA audio challenge working... oddly

Tags: google-api, recaptcha

I've just finished implementing Google's "No CAPTCHA ReCAPTCHA" system.

However, when I test the "audio challenge" option I notice that I can't click on the link, play the clip, click back to the form and enter the numbers I hear. In fact, I can't seem to enter numbers at all unless I manipulate the form exclusively through the keyboard (using TAB and SPACEBAR).

I'm trying to understand why that is. I realize that if I was completely blind I wouldn't be pointing and clicking my way through the form. However, what if my vision was only somewhat limited and I could click around the web just fine, but I had difficulty solving the CAPTCHA and prefered the audio option. Why prevent me from using that hybrid flow?

If this is an intentional limitation I'd love to see some documentation explaining it. If it's a bug I'd like to know that it's being worked on (or will be). If I am somehow "doing it wrong" I'd like to know what my error is.

Thank you for your time.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo in a incognito
   Google Chrome tab
2. Click the box to the left of "I'm not a robot"
3. Select the headphone icon / "Get an audio challenge"
4. Click inside the box and attempt to type (Or click the "Download audio as MP3"
   link, play the audio and return to the form tab and try to type what
   you hear into the box.

Expected: The placeholder text is removed and your text appears, you are then able to click the verify button.
Actual: The placeholder text remains and you are unable to input your text. Consequently you are unable to click the verify button and submit the form.

(Note that the expected behavior does occur if instead of clicking you hit SPACEBAR and use TAB to manipulate your way around the form.)

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I've also asked this on the Google ReCaptcha forms where others have reported this problem(?): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/XxteplB6Pug